# How replace part of the code in html files using terminal on Mac

Tags: html, macos, replace, terminal, command

I have a thousand .html files and I need to replace some of the code. But the command is not working correctly.

I use this command

```
gsed -i "s#.*CODE1#CODE2#g" **/*.html
```

Where CODE1 its lines of code for exemple `<div class="logotype"><a><img src="logo1.svg"></a></div>`

CODE2 its `<div class="logotype"><a><img src="logo2.svg"></a></div>`

Comment: Did you properly escape the CODE1 and CODE2 strings?

Comment: You think no properly? It's command works if its simple text. But if this is "line of code" doesn't work(